# Smtp Mail send times out

Tags: vb.net, smtp

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num As Integer = 0
    For intLoopIndex = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)
        SmtpServer.Port = 465
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False

        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "AT&T" Then
            mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text + "@txt.att.net")
            mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text)
            mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text
            mail.Body = RichTextBox1.Text
            SmtpServer.Send(mail) '<-- times out here

        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "7-11 Speakout" Then
            mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text + "@cingularme.com")
            mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text)
            mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text
            mail.Body = RichTextBox1.Text
            SmtpServer.Send(mail) '<-- times out here
        End If
        num = num + 1
        Label1.Text = num
    Next intLoopIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Process.Start("http://www.fonefinder.net/")
End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this code I get an error when it tries to send the email. When I run the program I get a generic timeout error with, for example, Verizon.  I am using correct login details for a GMail account and I've tried every fix I've found online. It does it with every carrier (mail server) I have.

Comment: The Timeout exception should contain additional details.  Also, try using telnet to connect to verify that you have the correct configuration.  (gmail uses port 587 and host smtp.gmail.com)

Comment: To begin, do this `Try SmtpServer.Send(mail)  Catch (ex as Exception) MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()) Debug.WrtiteLine(ex.ToString()) End try`. Then add full text from that to your question

Comment: Also, see this `http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/sending-email-via-gmail-in-cnet-using-smtpclient`